# Does this ‘twice’ mean two times, or double in quantity?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

> She caught sight of Mr. Diggory’s feet, and slowly, tremulously, raised her eyes to stare up into his face; then, more slowly still, she looked up into the sky. Harry could see the floating skull reflected **twice** in her enormous, glassy eyes.
>   (p134, Harry Potter 4, US edition)

NB – **The floating skull** is an ill omen, which a gangster launched into the sky by using magic, to show that his group is going to do bad things.
The sign is illuminating the entire wood like some grisly neon sign. 
‘**She**’ is an innocent passerby with big eyes. **Mr. Diggory** is a kind of policeman who thinks she is the gangster.

I’d like to know what the ‘twice’ means.

When I ran into the sentence, I thought she blinked and the sign reflected two times in her eyes, though there’s no ‘blink’ like expression around the sentence.
Then, another idea occurred to me that the sign reflected in her two eyes, one by one.

Would you give me the right meaning of the ‘twice’?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is meant to refer to one reflection in each of her two eyes. There is no mention of blinking, nor any reason to think that the idea blinking is meant to be raised.  Also, a blink would usually be thought of as interrupting a reflection rather creating a new reflection.  Because eyes are convex, each of the two eyes normally shows a reflection of its own of each visible item in the environment.

Comment: I’m feeling as if a fog had cleared up. I can sleep well tonight. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @mgkrebbs

This shows the "twice" if you look closer

[image: Reflection]

Comment: @mplungian - At first I was surprised, picture staring at me. But looking closely, it’s very ‘twice’! Great! Thanks. And the linked URL showed me a good writing.

Comment: It is not a skull that is reflected twice - I have removed the dead link now

Answer (score 0):

In math, "twice" also means "two-times".  In the original context, I believe she wen from seeing 1 skull to seeing 2 skull, 1 skull reflected in each eye.

There is a difference between something being "two times **longer than**...."  and "two times **as long as**... "  Say something is 10 ft.

A 30 foot object is two times longer than the 10 ft object.  (longer implies concatenated to the original.

A 20 foot object is two times (or twice) as long as a 10 ft object. 
I work with teachers and they have trouble with this distinction.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I randomly landed on this page and it got me thinking...

When *twice* is used to describe a verb, it means "two times". When it is used to describe a noun, it means "double in quantity".

This is a rather confusing example. What word is being described by *twice* can be debated.

> Harry [could see] the floating skull reflected [twice] in her enormous, glassy eyes.
>
> Harry could see the floating skull [reflected twice] in her enormous, glassy eyes.

Depending on how you read the sentence, *twice* can be describing either *see* or *reflected*. Regardless, both are verbs and therefore *twice* should mean "two times".

Comment: Since this didn't really answer the question, it probably should have been a comment, not an answer. We want people (even non-native speakers) to be able to search the site for answers, so we really want high-quality answers. After you get a response to a comment, you may see how to write the perfect answer.